# Can I count and list how many times words were used in an excel document?

Tags: r, excel, text, tm, corpus

I am working on analyzing some text data from a Ticketing system. I am pulling out long text fields from the tickets and need to analyze which words are being used and which ones are being used the most. But I need it to list all of the words.

The file format is in Excel and I have taken the file and using tm, I have made some edits to the data and removed some stop words and other words that aren't really important to the data I am looking for. I have already made this into a corpus.

When I do the following code it kind of gives me what I need but it does not actually give me all of the words. I know that this is going to be a long list, but that is fine.

```
dtm <- DocumentTermMatrix(hardwareCN.Clean)
dtmDataFrame1 <- as.data.frame(inspect(dtm))
colSums(dtmDataFrame1)
```

This gives me only about 10 words, but I know that there are many many more than that. I also then need to be able to export this to share.

Thanks

Comment: I think the problem is that your second step reduces the `dtm` to just the first 10 rows and columns because you use `inspect()`, which is just meant to eyeball the first bit of the matrix. Try running `dtmDataFrame <- as.data.frame(dtm)` instead and see if that does it.

Comment: That makes sense! I tested it and it gave me the error: "cannot coerce class ‘c("DocumentTermMatrix", "simple_triplet_matrix")’ to a data.frame" I found some other code out there with the same error and am attempting it but it is taking a while to load. I will let you know what happens